# SQL select all rows within a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

With the following table design:

```
Table "devices"
```

| model | serial_number | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11111 | 1 |
| A | 22222 | 1 |
| A | 33333 | 1 |
| A | 44444 | 0 |
| B | XXXXX | 1 |
| B | YYYYY | 1 |

I would like to retrieve the model, a count of the number of active devices (`active = 1`) for each model, and a list of all serial numbers for each model.

Expected output would be something like this:

```
[{
  "model": "A",
  "count": 3,
  "serials": ["11111", "22222", "33333"]
}, {
  "model": "B",
  "count": 2,
  "serials": ["XXXXX", "YYYYY"]
}]
```

I am able to retrieve the (grouped) models and count but how do I get the serial numbers?

```
SELECT model, count(*) as count
  FROM devices
  WHERE active = 1
  GROUP BY model
```

I suspect I need a sub-query but I can't wrap my head around this. Thanks.

Comment: What DBMS did you use? BTW your JSON seems invalid from your expected result

Comment: MS-SQL Server. That *expected result* was just a representation... I changed it for valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `FOR JSON PATH` with `STRING_AGG` function which will group connect string `serial_number` from each `model`

`QUOTENAME` will help you make `[]` array brackets

```
SELECT model, 
       count(*)  'count',
       JSON_QUERY(QUOTENAME(STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(serial_number, 'json') + '"', ',')))  serial_number
FROM devices
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY model
FOR JSON PATH
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b860373c7727c8af42963a2cef1600d)

If you don't want to get `JSON` result you might use `STRING_AGG` function directly.

```
SELECT model, 
       count(*)  'count',
       STRING_AGG(serial_number, ',') serial_number
FROM devices
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY model
```

Comment: As I said, the (JSON) output was just a representation of how I expect the data out of my query. I didn't say I needed it as JSON... I use PDO with PHP for my queries. So I suppose I could do it without the JSON_QUERY, right? Thx.

Comment: But you say *Expected output would be something like this* that was JSON format from your question.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Dose this one for your expectation? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=55b705eefd1d6eb0adb8b0f25f201575

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make myself clear. I wouldn't use string aggregation if that's feasible.

Comment: This query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=55b705eefd1d6eb0adb8b0f25f201575  is your expectation 
but you don't want to use string aggregation. Is that correct? Why don't you want to use string aggregation function?

Comment: I am wondering now how else it could be done. That would do it actually. I'd just need to explode these serial numbers in my PHP code before output (need to output each serial as a link...). Yes that query you shared is good.

Comment: I have a separate table with details about each device. Say for example the date of purchase. Would I be able to retrieve this additional information with a subquery in an array or object?